# Funny .toggleClass()

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I'm using some pretty simple .toggleClass() with animation of 1 second.Everything works fine,except the animation. I'm finding this really funny.

Look at my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Code_me/5dyT7/)!

```
$(function(){

 $('#main_button').click(function(){
 $('#one, #two, #three, #four').toggleClass("width", 1000);
 return false;
});
});
```

Comment: I don't know what you expect, but I see nothing, and really don't see how this code is supposed to lead to anything?

Comment: There is no animation in your code. What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JQuery UI extends toggleClass to allow for animations, but the default JQuery .toogleClass() won't animate. You need to include JQuery UI in your fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){

 $('#main_button').click(function(){
 $('#one, #two, #three, #four').animate({'width' :'toggle'}, 1000);
 return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

         $('#main_button').click(function(){
         $('#one, #two, #three, #four').slideToggle({'width' :'toggle'}, 
        1000);
          return false;
          });
        });
```